# How to select circle in Agar.io?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating an user-script for Agar.io but i have to select the circle of the player (the circle with the nick). Is possible selecting the circle with document.querySelector()?

Comment: Is there something you tried, it won't be easy to select an element from the whole canvas.

Comment: I know, for this i ask to you

Answer (score 0):

The circle you control is not a DOM element. It is drawn on the canvas with `id="canvas"`.

This means you can't use `document.querySelector()` to select the player. You'd need to find the actual JS variable name associated with the player object if you want to modify its properties.

Comment: How to can I found this variable name?

Comment: The code was created to not be easily manipulated by cheaters. The player data is out of scope from the window. Furthermore, a lot of the core logic is handled by asm which is not easily alterable.